# Sitecore MVC Checkbox

Tags: checkbox, sitecore

In Sitecore MVC, FieldRenderer.Render(Item, "*Field Name*") automatically checks its field type. In another word, all XSLT extensions (sc:text, sc:image, sc:date, …) is affected by the RenderField pipeline.

But, I couldn't find sc:checkbox information and it doesn't show "CheckBox" in page edit mode. It just shows the value of the check box.

How can I make it show as like input type=checkbox in page editor?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the link only answer but the general approach here is to use a [Field Editor Button](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/maximizing-usability/posts/2012/09/using-custom-experience-buttons.aspx).

This will open a pop up window with the content editor style control for the field.

Answer (score 1):

If using a custom experience button is not an option for you, you can output different markup (i.e. your input button) to the client when the page mode is in 'Edit' mode.

This will allow you to present the author with the controls you wish to display, but still output the normal output values for end users.

If you are able to use controller renderings, you can use the controller to load a different view to make this easier, but otherwise you can use if statements within your View to output different markup.

Comment: Nice tip on providing an alternative view!